# Private Data Fusion instance can't write to private CloudSQL instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am learning about gcp and I got a question regarding the execution pipeline of Data Fusion. I have a private Data Fusion Instance and a private CloudSQL instance running postgres. I peered both of them to the same VPC (the VPC only contains one subnet). I also set up a ProxyVM for them, for that I was using this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/connect-to-cloud-sql-source), I did however need to change some things, such as the driver being used. The guide pointed out that I need to use the “normal” JDBC driver instead of the cloudSQL version. That however didn’t work for me, but it did work with the CloudSQL-Postgres JDBC driver. The connection seems to be successful, at least that’s what gcp is telling me.

The problem arises when I try to run a pipeline. The idea of the pipeline is just to transfer a csv file in google cloud storage into a table of the postgres cloudSQL instance. During the pipeline setup I also get no errors. The Error shows up once I deploy and run the pipeline and mentions “Schema validation failed.

Exact Error Message: “Exception while trying to validate schema of database table public."<table_name>" for connection jdbc:postgresql:///<db_name>.“

It’s also worth mentioning that when I convert the entire schema to “string” in the Database as well as in Data Fusion the “preview” mode runs successfully, but crashes again when I actually deploy and run it.

So my question is, what the problem cloud be.
For Dataproc I also read that if I deploy a Dataproc cluster in a new VPC (what I did) I need to set the appropriate Firewall rule (according to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/network)). I did set this rule.

Maybe I configured the VM wrong, or I just deployed the pipeline entirely wrong. I also am able to transfer Data from a on-Premise Database into GCP-Storage without any problems. Just when I use CloudSQL as a sink I get this Error.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you read that? https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/connect-to-cloud-sql-source#private-instances

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes I did, in fact it is the same guide I used and linked above

Comment: If you created the proxy VM, you have to test piece by piece: Connect to Cloud SQL from the Proxy VM, From another VM in the same VPC. Then it should work if those piece works... It's hard to debug network issues.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thank you, that actually indirectly solved my issue. The problem was that the Firewall allowed for the Data Fusion Instance to connect to the proxy vm. But it didn't allow access from the dataproc cluster. So after I added an additional rule that does just that it runs as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was following the guide too closely. In the guide it says the following during the VM-Setup:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-private-cdf \
--allow=tcp:22,tcp:${SQL_PORT} \
--source-ranges=$CDF_IP_RANGE --network=$NETWORK --project=$PROJECT
```

A firewall rule also needs to allow access for the `dataproc` cluster in the `VPC` to the proxy-VM. After I added that it worked as expected.